# How can we group objects and assign a generic color to the group in a RDF graph on AWS Neptune?

Tags: sparql, graph-databases, amazon-neptune, graph-notebook

Graph notebooks allow grouping and appearance customization for Property graphs. Is there any way do the same for RDF graph ?

Answer (score 0):

Currently the grouping options are not available when issuing SPARQL queries using graph-notebook but we are hoping to add those in a future release. There is an issue open to track this feature. https://github.com/aws/graph-notebook/issues/12